# Extract string from a given file using awk.

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I have a file **named.conf,** here  first i need to find **himanshu.com** and then extract the corresponding zone file i.e. **for1** , I don't know what parameters would be passed to the **awk** script to find pattern two lines below.

named.conf

```
options {


directory "/var/named";

};



zone "himanshu.com" in {
type master;
file "for1";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" in {
type master;
file "rev";
};
```

Comment: `grep -A2 himanshu.com named.conf|awk '{print $2}`

Comment: @Gaius `-A2` shows 2 lines below/after matching, not the **2nd** line below matching.

Comment: Plus, the `file` line might not be exactly 2 below the `zone` line. If this were true, you could do `grep -A2 himanshu.com named.conf | grep file | cut -d\" -f2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/himanshu.com/ {found=1} /^file/ && found {print $0; exit}' file
file "for1";
```

This command sets a flag called `found` when it sees `himanshu.com` and then prints out the `file` if the flag has been set.

Another way using `sed`:

```
$ sed  -n '/himanshu/,/}/{/^file/s/.*\"\(.*\)\".*$/\1/p}' file
for1
```

This command first gets all lines between `himanshu` and the next `}` (inclusive), then searches for `file` within that block and finally uses a regex to extract the name of the `file`.

Comment: this is a clever solution. it should work for OP's requirement. there is one exception, if in `himanshu` block, no `file` occurs, the awk and sed line may output the wrong file name. As I said, it may not be the case that OP should take care about.

Comment: that's easily fixed in the `sed` commmand, using `sed  -n '/himanshu/,/}/` to grab the whole block. (answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS="" -F'\n' '/zone "himanshu.com"/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^file /)print $i}' file
file "for1";
```

the above line will first focus on the `zone "himanshu.com"` block, then extract the `file ...` line. no matter it locates how many line after the `zone "hi..."` line.

Comment: I would add that if  your `zone "him..."` block contained empty lines, the solution will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk command,

```
$ awk '/zone "himanshu.com"/ {getline; getline; print;}' file
file "for1";
```

OR

Run the below command to get the exact file name,

```
$ awk '/zone "himanshu.com"/ {getline; getline; print $2}' file
"for1";

$ awk '/zone "himanshu.com"/ {getline; getline; gsub (/";/,"",$2); gsub (/^"/,"",$2); print $2}' file
for1
```

Answer (score 0):

awk variation:

```
awk -F\" '$1~/zone/ && $2==s, /}/ {if($1~/file/) print $2}' s=himanshu.com file
```